# Keras.module needs Tf version=>2.2, but DLL's Tf load failed

Tags: tensorflow, keras, module

This is my first question here, 'cos I am normally able to find someone else asking the same question in stackoverflow and the answers are usually very clear and detailed.

Unfortutately this time I find myself in a corner.

I am using anaconda3 (64bit) from a Win10 and I would like to import

```
from keras.models import Model
```

Unfortunately I get the following issue:

```
 File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    'Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. '

ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`
```

When I have updated tensorflow to the newest version possible "2.3", I believe, but unfortunately this conflict with this other problem:

```
In [1]: import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-64156d691fe5>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf

  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util

  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context

  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe

  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `tf.keras.Model`

Keras is implemented by default in Tensorflow 2.0

Comment: this is a good trick, that I am using right now, thanks! I wonder if everything under Keras, can be really found under tf.keras.

Comment: Its is, keras project is now part of Tensorflow and francois chollet keras creator work under google